# which database will I use with Sys.Services.AuthenticationService.get_isLoggedIn()

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, forms-authentication

I read this article and examine source code. But I cant understand that which database have he used.

And I have a database and table named "users" and field of "username" and "password" and "roles". So I want to use Sys.Services.AuthenticationService.get_isLoggedIn().

And I cant understand how reach my database and query recorded user and return answer..
Can u give same example..
thanks..

Answer (score 0):

MSDN :

> Sys.Services.AuthenticationService.get_isLoggedIn: The value of
>   this property is set by the ScriptManager object during a page
>   request.

So, if my understanding is good, this value should be the same as HttpRequest.IsAuthenticated property. You just have to do normal authentication in server side code (using ASP.NET membership or FormsAuthentication) to automatically have this property set.